# Looking for Rubbermaid "Servin' Saver™" container

Tags: storage, containers

I'm looking for a specific Rubbermaid "Servin' Saver™" container. My co workers and I are having trouble finding it.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

[image]

Measurements are 9 in x 4.5 in x 2 in.

Measured as length width and height

Comment: It is actually 'tupperware' brand?  Are there any other markings on it?

Comment: @joe It is Rubbermaid it says 4 cups, 940 ml. It had a giant 5 on the right side with a square around it and under the Rubbermaid it says "Servin' Saver™"

Comment: Maybe they are discontinued ?

Comment: If this is for a commercial operation: Do rubbermaid not answer requests from business customers directly if asked?

Comment: It's considered 'vintage' (1980s?).  I found the lid for $15 (plus shipping) : https://www.amazon.com/Vintage-Rubbermaid-Rectangularl-Replacement-Container/dp/B00MW672DS/ref=sr_1_5?s=home-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1487785195&sr=1-5&keywords=rubbermaid+servin%27+saver

Comment: @joe it's close the height is too little but yeah they might be discontinued. Is it possible to ask them to make it for us?

Comment: I doubt the manufacturer would do a special run, but I found quite a few on eBay. Have you looked there?

Comment: No mind linking them?

Comment: http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.TRS0&_nkw=Rubbermaid+%E2%80%9CServin%27+Saver%E2%84%A2%E2%80%9D+container&_sacat=0

Comment: The reason I won't buy or use older (vintage) plastic food containers is there's been a big change in the chemistry of plastic over the years. Most (all?) of the old plastic absorbed the food's odor and tainted anything that was placed in it later. Any fats or oil in the stored food would end up, over time, reacting with the plastic leaving a sticky gummy feeling behind that no amount of detergent fixed. As well, a lot of older plastic food containers weren't really food safe. I'm still not 100% sure they all are now but a HUGE improvement to the older plastics.

Comment: @Jude Not used for food

Comment: Not used for food is perfectly acceptable then!

Comment: @Jude Yea the use we have for them needs those exact dimensions which is why I really need them

Comment: Hope you get them then.

Comment: @Jude it's been 3 years, no luck so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are listed as "vintage" on Amazon and eBay so I would think they are not being made any more. I found one on Amazon for $14.00 plus $5.49 shipping. There are some complete top and bottom sets on eBay but they are (relatively) expensive, around $15.00 each. I saw similar reusable containers on Amazon for a much more reasonable price, around $1-2.00 each.
And No, I am not affiliated with eBay or Amazon. :)